# Uniform distribution on a line segment

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

a. A point is chosen uniformly at random on a line segment of length *L*, dividing the segment into two parts. Find the probability that the longer of the two parts is at least twice as long as the shorter part.

b. Again a point is chosen at random on a line segment of length *L*, dividing the segment into two parts. This  time the location of the random breaking point has pdf:

$$f_X(x) = { 6x(L-x) \over L^3}, where: 0 \le x \le L $$

Find the probability that the longer of the two parts is at least twice as long as the shorter part.

**What I have tried so far:**

a. I am really stuck on where to begin. Could someone give me a start in the right direction.

b. same as part (a)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

a) Actually you are asked to find $P(X\leq\frac13L\vee X\geq\frac23L)$ for $X$ having uniform distribution on $[0,L]$.

b) Similar situation with other distribution.

Answer (score 0):

a. You are looking for $Pr\{X/(L-X)\geq 2\}+Pr{(L-X)/X)\geq 2}$; after transformation, it is exactly $Pr\{X\leq 1/3L\}+Pr\{X\geq 2/3L\}$, which can be obtained easily through the CDF.

b. Similar to a., you need CDF of the distribution. It is easy since you already know the PDF of $X$